# "Assertion '__builtin_expect(__n < this->size(), true)' failed" error in Visual Studio Code Python

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-code, fedora

I know there is already a lot on Assertion Failure. But none was useful for me. Hear me out.

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
from outliertree import OutlierTree

### random data frame with an obvious outlier
nrows = 100
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "numeric_col1" : np.r_[np.random.normal(size = nrows - 1), np.array([float(1e6)])],
    "numeric_col2" : np.random.gamma(1, 1, size = nrows),
    "categ_col"    : np.random.choice(['categA', 'categB', 'categC'], size = nrows)
    })

### test data frame with another obvious outlier
df_test = pd.DataFrame({
    "numeric_col1" : np.random.normal(size = nrows),
    "numeric_col2" : np.r_[np.array([float(-1e6)]), np.random.gamma(1, 1, size = nrows - 1)],
    "categ_col"    : np.random.choice(['categA', 'categB', 'categC'], size = nrows)
    })

### fit model
outliers_model = OutlierTree()
outliers_df = outliers_model.fit(df, outliers_print = 10, return_outliers = True) # gives error

### find outliers in new data
new_outliers = outliers_model.predict(df_test)

### print outliers in readable format
outliers_model.print_outliers(new_outliers)
```

This is the error:

> /usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_vector.h:1045: std::vector<_Tp,
> _Alloc>::reference std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[](std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = char; _Alloc = std::allocator; std::vector<_Tp,
> _Alloc>::reference = char&; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]: Assertion '__builtin_expect(__n < this->size(), true)'
> failed. Aborted (core dumped)

The error happens at line:

`outliers_df = outliers_model.fit(df, outliers_print = 10, return_outliers = True)`

Python version:

> Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 20 2021, 00:00:00)  [GCC 10.2.1 20201125
> (Red Hat 10.2.1-9)] on linux

OS:

> Fedora 5.10.12-200.fc33.x86_64

IDE:

> Visual Studio Code

Code works fine in Google Colab. So why is it happening only in the IDE? And if it's a setting or environment issue then what can I do? This is my first time working on Visual Studio Code.

Thank you

Comment: The error is about out of bounds array access. probably only enabled in debug builds, hence the difference with Colab (not 100% sure). Are you certain that your `df` has correct number of rows/columns? What if you don't print outliers? It can also be the case of https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1573253

Comment: I see that code for OutlierTree contains lots of patterns such as `&vec[0]` instead of `vec.data()`, which is likely an UB when vec.size() == 0: https://github.com/david-cortes/outliertree/blob/master/src/fit_model.cpp#L192
This is likely what triggers glibc assertions in your build. You can submit an issue/PR to the repo with suggested fixes/mentioning the problem, but nor sure what's the best recourse for you in the meantime.

Comment: @DanM.
I see you have already submitted an issue to the repo. Thanks for that.
Regarding whether df has the correct number of rows/columns, it should be, because this is the same sample code that they had given in their repo. 
Not printing doesn't change anything. It's exactly the call to the outliers_model.fit() with df that gives me this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Author of the library here. There was a bug in the code which would only trigger when the setup has defined a macro `_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS` and would otherwise not show up. It should be fixed now in the latest version (1.7.0) - please try again (`pip install -U outliertree`) and comment in the github issue tracker if the problem persists.

Comment: the same problem is there with R also now. Just letting you know!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know enough about OutlierTree to know how to fix the error. However, the error you see is in the function `std::vector::operator[]`, which is `std::vector`'s access by index function. The assertion error simply means that you tried to access an item at an index that is greater than the vector's length.

As to why you see this error only in VS Code, I assume that it's because assertions are usually checked only in debug mode. Google Collab is probably compiled in release mode without the assertions - that doesn't mean that you don't access out-of-bounds items, it just doesn't catch the error.

I suggest you use gdb or another debugger to understand which vector you try to access out-of-bound, then attaching a stacktrace to your question. Maybe file a bug report with OutlierTree - this seems something they could handle better.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I will see what I can do about trying another debugger. 
One of the other users who commented had already opened a report to the OutlierTree repo. Will see how that goes.
For now, am relying on Google Collab.

Comment: https://github.com/david-cortes/outliertree/issues/3